# Is there matlab function for Taguchi OA for 4 factors each at 2 levels?

Tags: matlab

I need to form an orthogonal array for 4 independent variables each at 2 levels.

I've tried on using oa_permut function in matlab by calling  A = oa_permut(2,4,3);

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47218-orthogonal-array

but it produces the following error:

```
Does not satisfy criteria ..

A =

     []
```

Also, this function doesn't help

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/60769-orthogonalarray-l_name-varargin

I need 8 experimental runs. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is such a function in MATLAB's file exchange:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/71628-taguchiarray/

Which you can use easily with :  `[Ta] = TaguchiArray(Q , N)`

`Q` being the levels and `N` the factors.